# How to add background full screen image and open a link if we press anywhere on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my code so far. I want my page having background full screen image and if i click on image it will open a link in a new tab.

Here is my CSS

```
html,
 body {
 /*css for full size background image*/
  background: url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover; 
 }
```

Here is my html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet"href 
 ="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <script 
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
 </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked into JQuery and the `on('click')` event?

Comment: please show what you have tried that isn't working. Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. The objective is for you to research how and show code that isn't working as expected

Comment: I don't know jquery or javascript. Although the image is not responsive right now. Check at this link. http://mapdc.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the image a "A" tag so the whole image is clickable, you can not make it clickable if its a css background image.

For the image to open up in a new tab you need to right it like this.

```
<a target:"blank_"  herf:"link" </a>
```